# Ellipse region shape from bivariate normal distributed data?

Tags: r, regression, density-function, bivariate

In my previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24380/how-to-get-ellipse-region-from-bivariate-normal-distributed-data) I needed to help with ellipse region extraction and determine if point lies in that region or not.
I ended up with this code:

```
library(ellipse)
library(mvtnorm)
require(spatstat)

netflow <- read.csv(file="data.csv",head=FALSE,sep=" ")
#add headers
names(netflow)<-c('timestamps','flows','flows_tcp','flows_udp','flows_icmp','flows_other','packe ts','packets_tcp','packets_udp','packets_icmp','packets_other','octets','octets_tcp','octets_udp','octets_icmp','octets_other')
attach(netflow)

#load library
library(sfsmisc)
#plot
plot(packets,flows,type='p',xlim=c(0,500000),ylim=c(0,50000),main="Dependence number of flows on number of packets",xlab="packets",ylab="flows",pch = 16, cex = .3,col="#0000ff22",xaxt="n")
#Complete the x axis
eaxis(1, padj=-0.5, cex.axis=0.8)

pktsFlows=subset(na.omit(netflow),select=c(packets,flows))
head(pktsFlows)
#plot(pktsFlows,pch = 16, cex = .3,col="#0000ff22")

cPktsFlows <- apply(pktsFlows, 2, mean)
elpPktsFlows=ellipse::ellipse(var(pktsFlows),centre=cPktsFlows,level=0.8)

png(file="graph.png")
plot(elpPktsFlows,type='l',xlim=c(0,500000), ylim=c(0,50000))
points(pktsFlows,pch = 19, cex = 0.5,col="#0000FF82")
grid(ny=10,nx=10)
dev.off()

W <- owin(poly=elpPktsFlows)
inside.owin(100000,18000,W)
```

This produces this [graph](https://github.com/matejuh/doschecker_wiki_images/raw/master/linear_regression/density/ellipse.png).

[image: graph ellipse]

Here is the same data with the [regression line plotted](https://github.com/matejuh/doschecker_wiki_images/raw/master/linear_regression/density/linRegAll.png)

[image: Plot all with linear regression line].

Can you explain me, why the ellipse has this shape? I expected that main axe of ellipse will have the same direction with linear regression line, but it hasn't.

Btw. [kernel density estimation](https://github.com/matejuh/doschecker_wiki_images/raw/master/linear_regression/kernel/kernelPoints.png) also points to 100000 althought there are no points...

[image: kernel density estimation]

Comment: Please see the [markdown help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) (you should have enough reputation to insert pictures into your post yourself now). I believe there are some other questions on this site that answer this question (or at least have pertinent discussion), see [Effect of switching response and explanatory variable in simple linear regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20553/1036) for one potentially helpful response.

Comment: "I expected that main axe of ellipse will have the same direction with linear regression line, but it hasn't."  This is a fundamental (but surprising) property of linear regression, called "regression to the mean."  (Do a search on that phrase. :-)  Unfortunately, I am unable to find any Web page containing a suitable illustration (in the form of a bivariate scatterplot)!  Introductory stats textbooks do, however, explain this phenomenon copiously.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you can see how the difference in orientation between the ellipse and the regression line changes depending on the correlation between x and y; higher is the correlation, closer is the agreement.

[image]

Comment: Very clear, nice job!