# How to detect an increase in a loess model fitted value at the end

Tags: r, regression, fitting, loess

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I'm not finding a proper idea for this issue.

I'd like to find if a series of fitted value of a loess is increasing in the end.

I'm working with some data like this:

```
data(economics, package="ggplot2")  
economics$index <- 1:nrow(economics) 
economics <- economics[1:45, ]
```

And I am fitting a `loess` model to them, using the base `R` function:

```
model_1 <- loess(uempmed ~ index, data=economics, span=0.40)
```

With this result for the fitted values:

```
plot(model_1$fitted, type ="line")
```

[image]

Is there a way to detect the last high increase of the fitted value?
I'm posting here because I am probably missing the point of something in the theory, rather than in the coding.

The only things I can think are arbitrary ways, like a condition *if the last value is x times bigger than the mean of the fitted values without it, so there is an increase*, or maybe a kind of *comparison of the mean of the last n values vs the mean of the previous m values*, but they seems too much subjective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225504/11849

Comment: @Roland , thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting to calculate a global maximum? If so, how can I decide if it's in the end? Sorry I think that could be a nice hint but I'm not grabbing how to use it.

Comment: The curve might go up or down at the end, so here is what I would try: find the peak-to-peak value of my data, and if the difference between a (smoother) quadratic and the loess is outside plus-or-minus half of the data peak-to-peak then I should have found this condition.