# Prediction Interval for Loess Forecast

Tags: r, regression, prediction-interval, loess

I have consulted this question on the basis of prediction intervals for loess ([How to calculate prediction intervals for LOESS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141552/how-to-calculate-prediction-intervals-for-loess)). **However, I am unaware of whether it is proper or possible to use prediction intervals for forecasts made from loess? What problems could come from doing so, if any? How would I do so in R?**

Currently I have attempted to calculate forecasts by using a for loop that predicts the values for a certain number of subsequent days, but I am unaware of how to produce prediction intervals for the same set of forecasts. I would hope to adjust the forecast so that my time-series and prediction look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Extrapolation from a LOESS is a big *no-no*...

Comment: @usεr11852 is this because too the weight is placed on locally? What other methods would you suggest for modeling data in which I want to extrapolate but also weight more recent observations?