# Do "line of best variances" exist?

Tags: variance, smoothing, scatterplot

I have a scatterplot and wish to know what the variance of the scatter along the $x$-axis. To illustrate with an [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/what-does-having-constant-variance-in-a-linear-regression-model-mean), the second column of plots correspond to points with increasing scatter in the $y$ direction as $x$ increases:

[image]

I am wondering what sensible ways are there to calculate the variance along all points of $x$ axis, particularly if the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ is not known in advance. That is, something like a line of best variance analogous to a smoothing line.

I will give some examples of what I am looking for. Using the above figures, the scale-location plots (bottom right) quantify the relationship of increasing variance with increasing $x$. This is obviously better than calculating a constant variance for all residuals (i.e. homoscedasticity assumption). However, a constant variance would have worked for the data on the left hand side column. In different situations, like for example [loess smoothing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141552/how-to-calculate-prediction-intervals-for-loess), we see that the variances can be quantified based on the standard error of the smoothing line, that is, the wider the band the more scattered the data:

[image]