# Proof for bivariate conditional mean of Gaussian dist

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate

I see that a lot of questions are answered here for multivariate and bivariate conditional distributions. But I did not find the proof of these equations (I need just for bivariate case).

[image]

[image]

to get this

[image]

I appreciate your help

Comment: There are plenty of proofs on this site.  I can point you to http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303 because I wrote it, but I'm sure that searching will turn up others (including others in that same thread).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the answer, Sorry for the duplicate! I did not find the one you mentioned here before asking