# Correlation coefficient for a uniform distribution on an ellipse

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, correlation, uniform-distribution

I am currently reading a paper that claims that the correlation coefficient for a uniform distribution on the *interior* of an ellipse

$$f_{X,Y} (x,y) = \begin{cases}\text{constant} & \text{if} \ (x,y) \ \text{inside the ellipse} \\  0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

is given by

$$\rho = \sqrt{1- \left(\frac{h}{H}\right)^2 }$$

where $h$ and $H$ are the vertical heights at the center and at the extremes respectively.

[image]

The author does not reveal how he reaches that and instead only says that we need to change scales, rotate, translate and of course integrate. I would very much like to retrace his steps but I am a bit lost with all that. I would therefore be grateful for some hints.

Thank you in advance.

Oh and for the record

> Châtillon, Guy. "The balloon rules for a rough estimate of the correlation coefficient." The American Statistician 38.1 (1984): 58-60

It's quite amusing.

Comment: Could you write down an expression for the ellipse? The _"height at the extreme"_ doesn't make sense for a standard ellipse: $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ since it has height $0$ at the extremes. Indeed, if $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the interior of the standard ellipse, then $\rho = 0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yeah, I tried the standard case and computed $\rho = 0$, no problems there. What about the other cases though, where you need to scale, rotate etc?

Comment: The entire operation appears fundamentally mistaken.  The "change scales" part destroys the uniformity.  A truly uniform distribution is achieved either as the limiting distribution within narrow (Euclidean) buffers of the curve or is uniform by arclength. In either case the normalizing constant is a complete elliptic function and won't possibly simplify to the expression given here. I'm not sure what $h$ and $H$ mean, but--as an example--the correlation coefficient for an ellipse with a major axis twice the minor axis, tilted at an angle of $\pi/6$, will be $0.78004$.

Comment: @whuber I have included a figure from the paper that explains what $h$ and $H$ stand for, I hope that this makes it clearer.

Comment: The picture helps immensely: not only does it show what $h$ and $H$ are, it shows that the distribution is *not* over the ellipse, but over its *interior*!  (The ellipse, by definition, is the curve.)

Comment: @whuber I apologise for the misunderstanding.

Comment: If you would like a full, complete answer, then you will find it in my post at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919.  After all, when the ellipse is a circle the uniform is (obviously) circularly symmetric, so just about everything in that answer applies directly.  In particular, by viewing the ellipse not as a rotation of a horizontal ellipse, but as a *skew transformation,* the formula for $\rho$ becomes obvious, because $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}=\lambda = h/H$ (using the notation in the section on "How to Create Ellipses").

Comment: @whuber Wow! I wish I had read your answer to the other question before spending so much time on my own answer to this question. Thanks for the learning experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed on the interior of the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ where $a$ and $b$ are the
semi-axes of the ellipse.  Then, $X$ and $Y$ have marginal densities
\begin{align}
f_X(x) &= \frac{2}{\pi a^2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\,\mathbf 1_{-a,a}(x),\\
f_X(x) &= \frac{2}{\pi b^2}\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\,\,\mathbf 1_{-b,b}(y),
\end{align}
and it is easy to see that $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$.  Also,
\begin{align}
\sigma_X^2 = E[X^2] &= \frac{2}{\pi a^2}\int_a^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \frac{4}{\pi a^2}\int_0^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \frac{4}{\pi a^2}\times a^4 \frac 12\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(3)}\\
&= \frac{a^2}{4},
\end{align}
and similarly, $\sigma_Y^2 = \frac{b^2}{4}$. Finally, 
$X$ and $Y$ are *uncorrelated* random variables.

Let \begin{align}
U &= X\cos \theta - Y \sin \theta\\
V &= X\sin \theta + Y \cos \theta
\end{align}
which is a *rotation* transformation applied to $(X,Y)$. Then,
$(U,V)$ are uniformly distributed on the interior of an
ellipse whose axes do *not* coincide with the $u$ and $v$ axes.
But, it is easy to verify that $U$ and $V$ are zero-mean
random variables and that their variances are 
\begin{align}
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{a^2\cos^2\theta + b^2\sin^2\theta}{4}\\
\sigma_V^2 &= \frac{a^2\sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta}{4}
\end{align}
Furthermore, 
$$\operatorname{cov}(U,V) = (\sigma_X^2-\sigma_Y^2)\sin\theta\cos\theta
= \frac{a^2-b^2}{8}\sin 2\theta$$
from which we can get the value of $\rho_{U,V}$.

Now, the ellipse on whose interior $(U,V)$ is uniformly distributed
has equation

$$\frac{(u \cos\theta + v\sin \theta)^2}{a^2}
+ \frac{(-u \sin\theta + v\cos \theta)^2}{b^2} = 1,$$
that is,
$$\left(\frac{\cos^2\theta}{a^2} + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{b^2}\right) u^2  + \left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{a^2} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{b^2}\right) v^2 
+ \left(\left(\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{b^2}\right)\sin 2\theta \right)uv = 1,$$
which can also be expressed as
$$\sigma_V^2\cdot u^2 + \sigma_U^2\cdot v^2 
-2\rho_{U,V}\sigma_U\sigma_V\cdot uv = \frac{a^2b^2}{4}\tag{1}$$
Setting $u = 0$ in $(1)$ gives 
$\displaystyle h  = \frac{ab}{\sigma_U}$.
while implicit differentiation of $(1)$ with respect to $u$ gives
$$\sigma_V^2\cdot 2u + \sigma_U^2\cdot 2v\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm du} 
-2\rho_{U,V}\sigma_U\sigma_V\cdot 
\left(v + u\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm du}\right) = 0,$$
that is, the *tangent* to the ellipse $(1)$ is horizontal at
the two points $(u,v)$ on the ellipse for which
$$\rho_{U,V}\sigma_U\cdot v = \sigma_v\cdot u.$$
The value of $H$ can be figured out from this, and will (in the
unlikely event that I have made no mistakes in doing the
above calculations) lead to the desired result.

Comment: That is a proper orthogonal rotation matrix, thank you.