# Epsilon from Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, random-variable, algorithms, expectation-maximization

I came across the following example from a book. I am given a dataset generated from a bivariate normal distribution:

[image]

Among the data, there are missing values for the last 20 of x2i (but not for x1i). The example demonstrates how EM algorithm comes into play to impute the missing value. The procedures are attached below:

[image]

It is further commented that the E-step conditional expectation is derived from the following formula:

[image]

I don't understand how this formula (the one with epsilon) is derived. Could anyone give me a reference for that?

Comment: The quotation is puzzling because you show us equation $(4.1)$ but the explanation refers to equation $(4.3)$ which isn't shown.  To give you a useful answer, we need definitions of all variables and all distributional assumptions that are being made.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have supplemented the post with more information. See if it is sufficient

Comment: Thank you: your question is clearer now.  I believe you can it answered in very many ways on our site: check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+normal+distribution.  I'm pretty sure I answered it at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919, for instance, using  elementary geometry, but of course there are many other ways to approach this.