# extract distribution of y for point x given lm of y~x

Tags: normal-distribution, prediction, lm

If I have two variables x and y that have a linear relationship e.g. using data from the mtcars package and R code

```
df <- mtcars[c(4,7)]
names(df) <- c("x", "y")

model <- lm(y~x, data = df)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

if I've test that my model doesn't violate any of the assumptions of lm, for each value of x there exists some distribution of y with a mean on the best fit line for the linear regression.

e.g. if I have a some thing with an x = 100 then my expected value of y will be ~ 18.75, but there will be some pdf around this

[image]

Is the correct way to set the parameters to take the predicted mean given the lm, and the sd of the entire distribution of y such that:

```
my_object <- data.frame(x = 100)
sd <- sd(df$y)
Ey <- predict(model, new = my_object, se.fit = TRUE)$fit
```

gives:
sd = 1.786943
Ey = 18.71

so if I now want to take multiple samples of y given x = 100 I can do

```
rnorm(1, Ey, sd)
```

taking the sd of the whole sample doesn't smell right but I can't think of any other way that you'd do it (if it is at all even possible)

[p.s. might be better suited to stackoverflow, but I assumed its more of a stats question]

Comment: @Minus Your comments might confuse the issue more than clarify it because the notation makes no distinction between the true (but unknown) parameter values and their estimates.  Robert: the intuition behind the issue you bring up (as well as a correct answer) is presented in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919.

Comment: ok- will probably have to wait until later to work my way through that answer to properly understand it, but from what I gather I want to take the sd of just the residuals around the lm?

(i.e. in R sd(model$residuals) )

thanks for the further reading both!

Comment: Robert Yes, that's correct: the objective of the regression is to estimate these conditional distributions.  The regression equation provides the formula for their (conditional) means and--because the usual assumption is that they all have a common variance--you may estimate that common variance by combining *all* the residuals.  (In more general circumstances you might look only at the residuals for values of $x$ close to $100.$)  The only subtlety concerns how best to estimate the variance of all the residuals.  Check out the formulas for Ordinary Least Squares regression.

Comment: Your picture of the Gaussian pdf (in red) is wrong. The x-axis should be vertical, not perpendicular to the regression line.