# Principal component analysis in two dimensions

Tags: pca, independent-component-analysis

During my studies, I stumbled upon the following exercise:

We have the following joint probability distribution:
$$p(x,y) = p(x) p(y|x)$$
$$p(x) = \mathcal{N}(0,1), p(y \mid x) = \frac{1}{2} \delta(y -x) + \frac{1}{2} \delta(y+x)$$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Direc delta function. The exercise then asks to find the principal components of $p(x,y)$. 
It is hinted that this is equivalent to finding the parameters $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi [$ that maximize the variance of the projected data: $z(\theta) = x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta)$, since in linear component analysis for two-dimensional probability distributions the set of possible directions to look for in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by:
$\{ \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi \}$.

Usually I would take the Lagrangian and the derive the maximum, but I don't know how the Langrangian would look like in this case. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: For any $\theta$, variance of $z$ is $1$

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on why that is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Since $E[z(\theta)]=0$, we have $$\operatorname{var}(z(\theta))=E[z(\theta)^2]=E[\cos(\theta)^2x^2+\sin(\theta)^2y^2+2\cos\theta\sin\theta xy]$$ Here, by definition, $E[x^2]=E[y^2]=1$. So, the expression reduces to:
$$\operatorname{var}(z(\theta))=1+\sin(2\theta) E[xy]$$
We also have $E[xy]=E[E[xy|x]]=E[xE[y|x]]=0$, which means $\operatorname{var}(z)=1$. 
This is an interesting dataset, the samples follow $y=x$ and $y=-x$ lines but we can't find these axes using this method. More importantly, $x$ and $y$ turns out to be uncorrelated.

Comment: +1.  But a picture alone would say (almost) everything.

Answer (score 2):

#### 4-fold rotational symmetry

The distribution looks like

```
n = 10^3
x = rnorm(n,0,1)
y = x*(rbinom(n,1,0.5)*2-1)

plot(x,y, pch=21,
     col=rgb(0,0,0,0.1),bg=rgb(0,0,0,0.1))
```

[image: example]

It has a 4-fold rotational symmetry which means that a quarter rotation leaves the distribution unchanged. That is $p(x,y) = p(-y,x)$.

For any bivariate distribution with a 4-fold rotational symmetry, there are no unique principle components.

#### Motivation

For any rotational transformation with an angle by $\theta$ we have that the sum of the variance of the transformed coordinates is invariant.

$$ \text{VAR}(X_\theta) + \text{VAR}(Y_\theta) = \text{VAR}(X) + \text{VAR}(Y) \tag{1}$$

Because of the symmetry we have that $$\text{VAR}(X_{\theta + 0.5 k \pi }) = \text{VAR}(X_{\theta}) \\
\text{VAR}(Y_{\theta + 0.5 k \pi }) = \text{VAR}(Y_{\theta}) \tag{2}$$

Because the axes are 90 degrees rotated from each other we also have

$$\text{VAR}(X_{\theta+ 0.5 \pi}) = \text{VAR}(Y_{\theta}) \\
\text{VAR}(Y_{\theta-0.5 \pi}) = \text{VAR}(X) \tag{3}$$

combining equations 2 and 3 it follows that for any rotation $\theta$

$$\text{VAR}(X_{\theta}) = \text{VAR}(Y_{\theta})$$

and because of equation 1, the variance must sum up to a constant, we have that after any rotation we will have that the variance of a coordinate is equal to halve the total variance.

The consequence is that we can not choose any unique direction for the components

Comment: Be careful, because there may be a flaw in this logic.  Everything hinges on the exact definition of "symmetrical."  The fact that the variances in the two *coordinates* are equal does not imply the principal components have equal variances!  What, then, are you claiming is symmetrical and what is the symmetry group?

Comment: @whuber if *any* two orthogonal transformated coordinates have equal variance, then the same will be true for the two principal components, which are orthogonal as well.

Comment: @whuber I get your comment when you are saying that I am not explaining the idea correctly/accurately, but the idea is correct right, or not?

Comment: As you know, I love demonstrations by symmetry or other insightful means that avoid calculations.  But that assertion in your first comment appears incorrect, at least as I interpret it.  As a counterexample I'm thinking of a Bivariate Normal distribution with equal unit variances and non-zero correlation coefficient (as illustrated in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919).  Specifically, the log density is $-(x^2+y^2-2\rho xy)/(2(1-\rho^2))+C.$ The *unique* PCs are parallel to $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ but they have *different* variances.

Comment: @whuber ah, ok, but the 90° rotational symmetry makes this different right? Do I just need to explain that better? I was thinking that any PC 2 must be 90° rotated to PC 1 and should be, due to the rotational symmetry, have the same variance. The distribution is the same after a 90° rotation.

Comment: Well, that's what I was wondering: what has rotational symmetry here?  Not the distribution $p$!  That has a $D_4$ symmetry group only.

Comment: @whuber any orthogonal transformation will have the axes at a 90° angle, and the variance of the coordinates along those axes will be the same because the distribution is invariant under a 90° rotation.

Comment: I hate to keep repeating, but -- orthogonal transformation of *what?*  Your conclusion about the variance seems to contradict the behavior of bivariate Normal distributions, where the variances along the coordinates *do* change under orthogonal transformations.

Comment: @whuber, I don't believe that that is the case if the bivariate normal distribution has a 4-fold rotational symmetry.

Comment: That is correct: but it needs proof (which admittedly is simple).  The result does not directly follow from some vague assertion of "rotational symmetry."

Comment: @whuber so you agree that the idea is correct? And it is only not sufficiently explained/proven? In the case of the latter, what is exactly vague? The idea that the distribution $p(x,y)$ has a 90 degrees rotational symmetry, or that this symmetry implies that the variance of the coordinates along two orthogonal coordinate axes are gonna be the same?

Comment: I agree that the idea is correct but just needs a clearer explanation. (And +1 for supplying it!)