# Zero conditional expectation implying zero covariance?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, covariance, conditional-expectation

Proof: E[X|Y]=0 implies COV[X,Y]=0

I was thinking maybe the law of total covariance or tower rule but couldn't come up with the proof

Comment: Hint: consider the expectation of $E[X\mid Y]Y.$

Comment: It's a direct application of tower rule.

Comment: Start by writing out the covariance definition out

Comment: If you would like details, see the equation immediately preceding the "Conclusions" section in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71260/what-is-the-intuition-behind-conditional-gaussian-distributions/71303#71303 and let $\rho=0.$