# conditional expectation of iid $X,Y$ cubic sum

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d standardized normally distributed random variables.

Calculate the conditional expectation of :
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^{3}  | \mathscr{G}] $$

where $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(X)$ ($\sigma$-field generated from $X$)

**Proposal**

$$X,Y \sim N(0,1)$$

$$\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)|X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (X+Y) f_{X+Y|X}(X+Y|X)dx$$

$X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables with density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$, respectively. First i find the density function of $X + Y$.

Secondly I use the first calculation in order  to find the density
of the sum of two independent standard normal random variables.

Conditioning on $X$:

\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}[X+Y|X]= P(X+Y \leq t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(X+Y \leq t |X=x)f_X(X)dx \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(Y \leq t-x |X=x)f_X(X)dx \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(Y \leq t-x)f_X(X)dx \\
\end{align*}
Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_y( t-x)f_X(X)dx  (1)$$

Now For $X$ and $Y$ independent standard normal random variables, by (1), the sum
$X + Y$  has density

\begin{align*}
    f_{X+Y}(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(t-x)^2/2}  \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-t^2/4} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi(1/2)}}e^{-(x-t/2)^2/2(1/2)}dx\\
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-t^2/4}
\end{align*}

Comment: $$(Y+X)|X\sim\mathcal N(X,1)$$

Comment: how?can you explain ?@Xi'an

Comment: Drawing a picture helps.  If you would like the details, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919.

Comment: @whuber I edited my question any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Taking out what is known"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834154/taking-out-what-is-known) is the basic property

$$E[X\mid \sigma(X)] = X$$

and therefore when $f$ is a measurable function of $X$ and $g$ is a measurable function of $Y,$

$$E[f(X)g(Y)\mid \sigma(X)] = f(X)E[g(Y)\mid \sigma(X)].$$

When $X$ and $Y$ are independent this further simplifies to $f(X)E[g(Y)].$

Use this fact along with linearity of expectation and the independence of $(X,Y)$ to compute

$$\begin{aligned}
E[(X+Y)^3\mid \sigma(X)] &= E[X^3+3X^2Y+3XY^2+Y^3\mid \sigma(X)] \\
&= X^3 + 3X^2E[Y] + 3XE[Y^2] + E[Y^3].
\end{aligned}$$

You don't have to integrate to find these moments of $Y,$ because you already have the information you need:

- Because $Y$ and $-Y$ have the same distribution and their first and third moments are finite, $E[Y]=E[-Y]=-E[Y]$ and $E[Y^3]=E[(-Y)^3]=-E[Y^3]$ show these expectations are zero.
- $E[Y^2] = \operatorname{Var}(Y)+E[Y]^2 = 1+0=1.$

Comment: so I have to integrate only $\mathbb{E}[-Y^3]$?

Comment: or just the $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} yf_{Y|X}(Y|X)dy$$

Comment: So according to these I will have $x^3+3x$

Comment: For $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ we have : 


\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} yf(y)dy &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y e^{-y^2/2}dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}y e^{-y^2/2}dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-y e^{-y^2/2} \\
&= \left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y e^{-y^2/2}\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \\
&=0
\end{align*}




Therefore : 
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^3\mid \sigma(X)] &=  X^3 + 3X^2\mathbb{E}[Y] + 3X\mathbb{E}[Y^2] + \mathbb{E}[Y^3]\\
&= X^3 + 3X^2\cdot 0 + 3X \cdot 1 + 0 \\
&= X^3 + 3X \\
& = X(X^2+3)
\end{aligned}$$