# Conditional expectation given sum of weighted average

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose X, Y are i.i.d standard normal (mean 0, standard deviation 1) random variables, a, b, c are constant scalars.

$$Z = a X + b Y$$

How to express $E[X|Z=c]$ using $a,b,c$?

Comment: Hint: this is an ordinary least squares regression problem, so you can just apply the standard formula for the conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Still searching for a quick solution, but anyway I solved the problem in brute force.

1. Prove that $f_{X,Z}(x_0,c) = \frac{1}{b} f_X(x_0) f_Y(\frac{c - ax_0}{b})$, where $f_{X,Z}$ is PDF of joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$
   (hint: use Leibniz integral rule and Fundamental theorem of calculus)
2. Prove $E[X|Z=c]=\frac{ac}{a^2+b^2}$ (hint: use definition of conditional expectation and PDF of standard normal random variable)

Comment: As I indicated in a comment to your question, you don't need to do this: it's simple to apply the OLS formula.  You can also look up the answer by searching [conditional normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=conditional%20normal).  It is also possible to avoid Calculus altogether, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks @whuber!

Answer (score 0):

You could express the relationship as $X = Z/a - bY/a$, which gives you that $X\mid Z=c$ is distributed as $c/a - bY/a$ which means it is $\mathcal{N}(c/a, b^2/a^2)$ therefore you get
$$\mathrm{E}[X\mid Z=c] = c/a$$
The absence of $b$ here comes from the fact $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: With this logic, we will have $E[Y | Z =c] = c/b$ by symmetry, but then $c = E[Z|Z=c] = E[aX + bY|Z=c] = aE[X|Z=c]+bE[Y|Z=c] = 2c$, so this result can't be correct when $c \neq 0$

Comment: Excellent point, I however do not see which step is incorrect...

Comment: I think we can't say $X = c/a - bY/a$, because that means $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Of course $X=Z/a - bY/a$ (at least when $a\ne 0$) because that's just applying a rule of arithmetic.  The error lies in (implicitly) assuming $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

a)$E(aX+bY|aX+bY)=aX+bY$,
so

$$aE(X|aX+bY)+bE(Y|aX+bY)=aX+bY \tag{1}$$

b)Find $d$ such that $X-dY$ be independent([Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)) of $aX+bY$ so

$E(X-dY|aX+bY)=E(X-dY)=0$ and hence

$$E(X|aX+bY)=dE(Y|aX+bY) \tag{2}$$

$d$ can be computed as follows:
$$0=\text{cou}(X-dY, aX+bY)=a\text{Var}(X)-db \text{Var}(Y)=a-db$$
so $d=\frac{a}{b}$

Now use (1) and (2)

$$aE(X|aX+bY)+b(\frac{b}{a}E(X|aX+bY))=aX+bY$$ so

$$E(X|aX+bY)=(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2})(aX+bY)$$