# properties of conditional normal random vectors

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable

Given the partitioning: $X = 
\begin{pmatrix}{}
x_1  \\
\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}$ for a normal random vector with mean $\mu = 
\begin{pmatrix}{}
\mu_1  \\
\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$ and covariance matrix:

$\Sigma =  
\begin{pmatrix}{}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}  \\
\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ where $\Sigma_{22}$ is invertible. How can I understand the following mean,covariance of a distribution of a random variable $X_1$ under condition $X_2 = x$? I'm struggling with formula for both the mean and covariance which are given specifically as:

$\mu_1 +\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x-\mu_2) $

and

$\Sigma_{11}- \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$.

I'm just getting into multivariate statistics, so I would preferably just try to get some intuition behind these two formulas if possible.

Comment: A great deal of intuition can come from studying the simplest (nontrivial) case: see our thread on this at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71260.  If that doesn't answer your question, could you please indicate what you might be looking for in addition?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That solves my problem completely.