# Covariance in multivariate Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, gaussian-mixture-distribution

In a single dimension Gaussian, the variance $\sigma$ denotes the expected value of the squared deviation from the mean $\mu$.

I am trying to understand why in the multivariate case of modeling variable $\mathbf{x}$ we end up having a matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$. Why not instead of a vector which in each dimension shows the variance of the input variable $\mathbf{x}$.

From Wikipedia the 2d Gaussian function is represented as:

$f(x,y) = A \exp\left(- \left(\frac{(x-x_o)^2}{2\sigma_X^2} + \frac{(y-y_o)^2}{2\sigma_Y^2} \right)\right)$

Why not use a form like that for the multivariate Gaussian with $\mathbf{\sigma} = [\sigma_{X} \ \sigma_{Y}]^{T}$? Given than my vector $\mathbf{x} = [x \ y]^{T}$.

How this is interpreted in the following example:

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of the concept of correlation between random variables?

Comment: Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71260 will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [probability density function for Bivariate Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) is

$$
f(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \mathrm{e}^{
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 -
          2\rho\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)\left(\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right) +
          \left(\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)^2 
        \right]
      }
$$

notice that apart from $\mu_X,\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y$, it has the $\rho$ parameter for the correlation between the $X$ and $Y$ variables. If they are uncorrelated, i.e. $\rho=0$, the pdf reduced to what you described.

The same applies to multivariate normal, you could use a covariance matrix that is all-zeros, with the $\sigma$'s on the diagonal. In such a case, the individual variables are assumed to be uncorrelated.

Comment: IIs there a way to explain this visually? How the correlation affects the Gaussian?

Comment: @JoseRamon are you familiar with [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)?

Comment: yes, I am trying to grasp the reason that why make use of it in our case.

Comment: @JoseRamon to have a distribution for variables that are Gaussian and correlated. If you don't need that, you don't need the distribution.

Comment: I understand what is the covariance matrix, but I am not sure why it is necessary and what it represents in the multivariate case.

Comment: @JoseRamon it represents the covariance matrix between the variables that together form the multivariate distribution.

Comment: that does not really answer my question. Visually in the example, I have posted, why the variance in the two dims $\sigma_{X}$ and $\sigma_{Y}$ isn't enough to be used?

Comment: @JoseRamon because it tells you nothing about [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) between the variables.