# How Difficult is it to Determine the Conditional Distribution of a Non-Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

I have the following question about **How to Determine the Conditional Distribution of a Non-Normal Distribution**.

When dealing with the Multivariate Normal Distribution, there is well-established theory and clear procedures on how to calculate the Conditional Distribution:

[image]

**However, I have the following question:** When dealing with Non-Normal Distributions, how do we determine their Conditional Distributions?

- In the case of Mixture Normal Distributions, I think that you can use the above formula to evaluate the Conditional Probability Distributions of each individual Normal Distribution within the mixture - and then simply sum the Conditional Mixtures. I think this should be reasonable?
- However, in the case of Non-Normal Distributions - is there a standard method to determine their conditional distributions? For instance, if you have a joint probability distribution of some Non-Normal Distribution in 3 variables P(X,Y,Z) and you want to find out P(X, Y | Z =  1.2) : I don't think that simply substituting "Z = 1.2" into the joint density is acceptable. I think that in theory, MCMC Sampling methods can be use to generate samples from any conditional probability distribution - however, this requires you to know the "general functional form" of that conditional distribution : MCMC allows you to calculate integrals of functions that don't have analytical solutions - however, you must be able to define these functions before you can perform MCMC!

For example, if we take a multivariate Tweedie Probability Distribution (I use this example because it is the most "non-normal looking" probability distribution that comes to mind) :

[image]

**Question:** When dealing with clearly Non-Normal Probability Distributions (e.g. Tweedie Distributions, Gamma Distributions) - are there any standard methods for defining and calculating their conditional probability distributions? Does this problem often occur in statistics?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution

Comment: I do not see the difficulty: if $p(x,y,z)$ is of a known functional form, the conditional is equally available as$$p(x,y|z)\propto p(x,y,z)$$

Comment: In terms of computability, it's not always possible to determine a conditional distribution: https://cfreer.org/papers/AckermanFreerRoyCompCondProb.pdf