# Random variate of a singular Wishart distribution with non-integral degrees of freedom

Tags: multivariate-distribution, wishart-distribution

Let's say that I have a random variable $X$ that follows a singular Wishart distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and a shape matrix $\Sigma$ that is $p\times p$. We can write "symbolically":
$$X\sim W_p(\nu,\Sigma)$$
where $\nu\le p-1$ for the singular case.

If $\nu$ is integral then I can get a random variate by simply taking $\nu$ independent random normal variables $Y_i=\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ is the normal distribution with no mean and a covariance of $\Sigma$. Then my random variate will be:
$X=\sum_{i=1}^\nu Y_iY_i'$. If $\nu$ is less or equal to $p-1$, this random variate will be non-invertible with probability of one.

Let's say that I would like to get a random variate for a non-integral value of $\nu$, for example $\nu=\frac12$. In this situation, I obviously can't use the summation of normal variables. What would be the appropriate way to get a random variate for such value of $\nu$?

Also, I am not sure it makes perfect sense to have a random variate for $\nu=\frac12$ as if I sum two independent variates of this kind then I can't ensure that the rank of my random variate will be $1$ as what it should be normally ($1=\nu+\nu$).

Comment: I haven't dug in to figure out what the code is actually doing yet, but: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6b22b60126646714e0f25143ac679240be251dbe/src/library/stats/src/rWishart.c

Comment: @BenBolker in the code, there is this statement: `if (nu < (double) p || p <= 0) error(_("inconsistent degrees of freedom and dimension"));`. However, I can define a proper variate for $\nu$ integral. It will just be singular with probability of $1$, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Bartlett_decomposition.

Comment: It is valid for every mathematically possible df.

Comment: I'm just not sure the distribution is properly defined for this edge case. For some cases (say `p = 4, nu = 2`) you could pick a Wishart with `p=2, n=2` and then apply a rotation matrix to get the desired location? maybe?

Comment: I think that the suggestion from @whuber will work, it's just a matter of writing it properly.

Comment: I believe your proposed method to generate a Wishart variate is incorrect.  This is because when $\Sigma$ is the identity, it produces only diagonal matrices, which when $p\gt 1$ would obviously not form a Wishart distribution (for which *all* psd matrices have positive density).

Comment: @whuber Maybe I don't understand the argument but I don't see why it would only produce diagonal variates. If $\Sigma$ is the identity (let's say $2\times2$) then it just means that we have a bivariate $\mathcal N(0,I_2)$ with no correlation. For $\nu=1$, that will still produce a rank 1 matrix which is not diagonal with probability 1. I do think that there is a limitation on $\nu$ though, unless we have $\nu>p-1$ then $\nu$ must be integral. If not, we can't get a proper matrix rank with the property that $W(a,\Sigma)+W(b,\Sigma)\sim W(a+b,\sigma)$.

Comment: I meant $W_p(a,\Sigma)+W_p(b,\Sigma)\sim W_p(a+b,\Sigma)$ in the last comment (typo), where the 2 Wishart distributions on the left are independent. The context here is that, if $a\le p-1$ or $b\le p-1$ then we have singular distributions, which are OK but then the degree of freedom need to be integral so the rank are consistent. Once we reach $p-1$ then the matrices are full-rank with probability $1$ and we can have non-integral degrees of freedom.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot recognize the Wishart distribution in any of your characterizations in those recent comments.  When $\Sigma$ is the identity you obtain a distribution over *all* psd matrices.  Almost surely any realization has rank $p$ and almost surely all its coefficients are nonzero.

Comment: I am looking here specifically at the singular Wishart, with a degree of freedom insufficient to generate a psd matrix. See for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#The_range_of_the_shape_parameter). The density of probability for $\nu<p-1$ is singular and the usual pdf formula will not be valid. We can still generate random variate, either using your suggestion (Bartlett decomposition) or by drawing $\nu$ random samples from $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$. In the way I asked my question, the answer is negative (we need to have integral $\nu$) if we want to...

Comment: ...ensure that the rank of the random variate is consistent with the number of degrees of freedom. I hope it clarifies what I tried to explain. It's the first time I dig in that region of the Wishart so my explanation was a bit confused earlier.

Comment: @whuber to understand what I mean by "singular Wishart", check my answer. This definition is consistent with the usual Wishart definition (for integral $\nu$) but it also covers the cases where $\nu<p-1$.

Comment: The problem is that at some point in your edits you (a) first introduced "singular" into the title--it was not originally there--but (b) never modified the question to reflect that.  It remains unclear whether your question is about Wishart distributions or singular Wishart distributions.  Furthermore, the question still focuses on "non-integral" parameters, whereas it appears you are really interested in *values of $p-1$ or less.*  I regret having spent any time attempting to answer a question that is so volatile and, even still, ill-defined.

Comment: Sorry it was not specified properly. I edited the question to leave it in a clearer state. This is the first time I look at the Wishart distribution (and its singular form) so I missed important infirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is negative, we must have an integral number of degrees of freedom $\nu$ if $\nu\le p-1$. To prove it, we can look at the singular Wishart, defined as:
$$W_p(\nu,\Sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^nY_iY_i'$$
with $Y_i\sim\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$, and $\Sigma$ a positive definite matrix.

The rank of the random variate will be $\nu$ almost surely if $\nu\le p-1$ and $\nu$ is integral. In order to keep the property that $W_p(\nu_1,\Sigma)+W_p(\nu_2,\Sigma)=W_p(\nu_1+\nu_2,\Sigma)$ for all $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$, we must ensure that $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are integral numbers. This can be seen from the definition of the singular Wishart above.

We can try to prove that there exists a way to define $W_p(\frac12,\Sigma)$ so adding two of these independent random variates will create a matrix of rank $1$ but that requires the two variates to share the same (degenerate) eigenspace. Unless we constraint it explicitly then we can't have this property. So we need to have $\nu$ integral until we reach full rank.

Answer (score 5):

The [Wishart Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) is defined on the manifold $\mathcal{M}(p)$ of all positive-definite symmetric (psd)  $p\times p$ matrices.  In the coordinate system $(x_{ij}, 1\le j \le i \le p)$ (which identifies this space of matrices with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p(p+1)/2}$) the density of the "standard" Wishart distribution with $n\gt p-1$ "degrees of freedom" at a matrix $x$ is given by

$$f_n(x) = C_n \det(x)^{(n-p-1)/2}\, e^{-\operatorname{tr}(x)/2}$$

where $C_n$ is the normalizing constant.  Given any specified positive-definite $p\times p$ matrix $V,$ another Wishart distribution can be generated upon multiplying a standard Wishart $x$ to produce $Vx.$  (This is the multidimensional analog of a change of scale: see "Higher Dimensional Geometries" at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/564628/919.)

One important property of this distribution is that the diagonal elements of $x$ will all have scaled chi-squared distributions with $n$ degrees of freedom.

**The Bartlett Decomposition,** as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Bartlett_decomposition), generates $x$ in the form $L^\prime AA^\prime L$ where $V = L^\prime L$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $V$ ($L$ is lower triangular), the diagonal of $A$ is a sequence of $\chi(n), \chi(n-1), \chi(n-p+1)$ variables (that is, square roots of chi-squared variables), and below the diagonal the components are standard Normal; all $p(p+1)/2$ of these variables are independent.  This gives a practical and fairly simple way to generate Wishart variables for any $V$ and $n$ that are mathematically possible.  This `R` function gives one implementation directly modeled on the Wikipedia article (using its notation).

```R
#
# Random Wishart matrices.
# Returns a rank-3 array indexed by the third variable.
#
rWishart <- function(n, V, df) {
  d <- dim(V)[1]
  L <- chol(V)
  X <- replicate(n, {
    A <- diag(sqrt(rchisq(d, df + 1 - seq_len(d))), d)
    A[lower.tri(A)] <- rnorm(d*(d-1)/2)
    Y <- crossprod(L, A)
    tcrossprod(Y)
  })
  array(X, dim = c(d, d, n))
}
```

As an example of its use, I set $$V = \pmatrix{2 & -3 \\ -3 & 6}$$ (whence $p=2$ and the implied correlation coefficient is extremely negative), specified the degrees of freedom in a variable `df`, and generated $20,000$ realizations from this Wishart distribution as

```R
X <- rWishart(2e4, V, df)
```

The result is a rank-three array.  That is, `X` has three subscripts.  Its last subscript determines one $p\times p$ matrix.  For instance, the first realization is `X[,,1]` and the last realization is `X[,,2e4]`.

Here are histograms of the components of these realizations for two different values of $n,$ $1 + 1/\pi \approx 1.32$ (close to the minimum of $1$) and $20$ (fairly large).  Because symmetry implies $x_{12}=x_{21}$ for any such realization, only three histograms are needed.  Notice the differing value scales among the plots.

[image: Figure 1]

On top of the histograms I have plotted the chi-squared distributions (left and middle histograms) and the "variance-Gamma" distribution for the off-diagonal $x_{12}$ component.  The agreement is good, indicating the formulas in the Wikipedia article are correct (and that the code has correctly implemented them).

Of course the components of a Wishart random matrix are not independent.  Here is a scatterplot matrix (of the first two thousand) of the previous results.  I show all four components to demonstrate the realizations are indeed all symmetric.  The color coding is the same as before.

[image: Figure 2]

The `R` code to produce the figures might be helpful, so it is reproduced below.

```R
#
# Example.
# This generates one set of realizations for each parameter value in `df,
# storing the results in a list `lX`.
#
set.seed(17)
V <- matrix(c(2,-3,-3,6), 2) # Must be psd
df <- c(1 + 1/pi, 20)
lX <- lapply(df, function(df) rWishart(2e4, V, df = df))
#
# Density of the off-diagonal elements.
# (Works only for 2D matrices!)
#
dvgamma <- function(x, V, df) {
  s <- prod(sqrt(diag(V)))
  rho <- V[1,2] / s
  y <- x / (s * (1 - rho^2))
  besselK(abs(y), (df-1)/2) * exp(rho * y) * abs(x)^((df-1)/2) / 
    (gamma(df/2) * sqrt(2^(df-1) * pi * (1 - rho^2) * s^(df + 1)))
}
#
# Plot histograms of the components.
#
sigma2 <- diag(V)
colors <- hsv(seq(0, 2/3, length.out=3), .25, .8)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in seq_along(lX)) {
  X <- lX[[i]]
  n <- df[i]
  hist(X[1,1,], freq=FALSE, breaks=102, col=colors[1], 
       main=bquote(df==.(1 + signif(n-1,2))), xlab=expression(X["1,1"]))
  curve(dchisq(x/sigma2[1], n)/sigma2[1], lwd=2, add=TRUE)
  
  hist(X[2,2,], freq=FALSE, breaks=102, col=colors[2], 
       main=bquote(df==.(1 + signif(n-1,2))), xlab=expression(X["2,2"]))
  curve(dchisq(x/sigma2[2], n)/sigma2[2], lwd=2, add=TRUE)
  
  hist(X[1,2,], freq=FALSE, breaks=102, col=colors[3], 
       main=bquote(df==.(1 + signif(n-1,2))), xlab=expression(X["1,2"]))
  curve(dvgamma(x, V, n), add=TRUE, lwd=2)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Plot the scatterplot matrix for one of the sets of realizations.
#
X <- lX[[1]]
panel.hist <- function(x, col) { # Modified from the man page for `pairs`
  COLOR <<- COLOR + 1
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE, breaks=20)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col=colors[COLOR])
}
colors <- colors[c(1,2,2,3)]
COLOR <- 0

e <- c(expression(X["1,1"]), expression(X["2,1"]), expression(X["1,2"]), expression(X["2,2"]))
pairs(t(matrix(X, 4))[1:2000, ], col="#00000020", diag.panel = panel.hist, labels=e)
```