# Finding expectation through conditioning

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate

[image]

I want to find $E(X^2Y^2)$. Now $Var(XY) = E(X^2Y^2)-E(XY)^2.$ Since $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ both are 0, $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)$ and $Cov(X,Y) = \rho \sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}. $ Therefore, $Cov(X,Y)=\rho.$ Therefore from previous argument, we have $E(XY)=\rho$. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Start by finding $E[X^2Y^2\mid X] = X^2E[Y^2\mid X].$

Comment: How do I calculate $E[Y^2|X]$ ? $\quad Y^2$ will be a chi square distribution with degree of freedom 1 right? How do I proceed further?

Comment: You could use the formulas at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up the hint from Moderator whuber, consider that when $X$ is and $Y$ are *jointly* normal random variables, the conditional distribution of $Y$, conditioned on $X = x$, is a *normal* distribution with mean
$\mu_y + \rho\left.
\left.\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\right(x-\mu_x\right)$ and variance $\sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)$.  Surely you can compute $E[Y^2\mid X=x]$ from this information without needing to evaluate any integrals and the like?