# What is the probability of $P(X>Y>0)$ where $X$ and $Y$ standard normal distribution with correlation $\rho$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

What  I  have done is use Cholesky decompostion to get $X = \rho X^{1}  + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}X^{2}$ and  $Y = X^{1}$ where  $X^{1}$ and $X^{2}$ are independent standard normal. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X>Y>0) &= P(X>Y,Y>0) \\
&=  P(\rho X^{1}  + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}X^{2} > X^{1},X^{1} > 0)\\
&= P(\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}X^{2} > (1 - \rho)X^{1},X^{1}>0)\\
&= P(X^{2} > \sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho}}X^{1},X^{1} > 0) \quad \quad \quad \text{ if } \rho \neq 1,-1
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus $P(X > Y >0) \in [\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4})$ when  $\rho \in [0,1)$  and $P(X > Y >0) \in(0,\frac{1}{8})$ when $\rho \in (-1,0)$ and $P(X > Y >0) = 0 $ for $\rho = 1,-1$. Does that right? Could anyone use the graph of the coordinates that are not vertical to figure out this question?

Comment: I would like to suggest that simply *looking* at the plots in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919 will enable you to write down a correct simple formula.  All you need to is reverse the transformations to find where the wedge $x\gt y\gt 0$ originated; the probability will equal the angle divided by $2\pi.$

Comment: Thank you! I will read  it now. By the  way, What  do you think about what I have done using  Cholesky?

Comment: I hope you will find it's equivalent to one of my two geometric descriptions ;-).

Comment: According to Abramowitz and Stegun 26.3.19, p 937, $$P(X>0, Y>0) - \frac 14 + \frac{\arcsin \rho}{2\pi}$$ and so, because of the symmetry, $P(X>Y>0)$ should be half that number.

Comment: @Dilip Which symmetry, specifically?

Comment: @whuber I guess Dilip means $P(X > 0, Y > 0) = P(X > 0, Y > 0, X > Y) + P(X > 0, Y > 0, Y > X)$, and the probabilities on the right hand side are identical to $P(X  > Y > 0)$.

Comment: @whuber Zhanxiong has already answered your question regarding symmetry. I apologize for the typo in my displayed equation; that $-$ should have been a $=$. Oh well, comments can’t be edited this late.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the joint density of $(X, Y)$ is $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 2\rho xy}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)$, the probability of interest is
\begin{align}
P(X > Y > 0) = \iint_{(x, y): x > y > 0}\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 2\rho xy}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)dxdy. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
A natural way of simplifying the integral $\eqref{1}$ is through the polar coordinates $x = \rho\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$, under which $\eqref{1}$ becomes
\begin{align}
P(X > Y > 0) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}\int_0^{\pi/4}\left[\int_0^\infty r\exp\left(-\frac{1 - \rho\sin(2\theta)}{2(1 - \rho^2)}r^2\right)dr\right]d\theta. \tag{2}\label{2} 
\end{align}
It is easy to show that inner integral of $\eqref{2}$ evaluates to $\frac{1 - \rho^2}{1 - \rho\sin(2\theta)}$, whence it suffices to evaluate the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{1 - \rho\sin(2\theta)}d\theta. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
One way to evaluate $\eqref{3}$ is considering the transformation $\theta = \arctan(u)$ (inspired by the [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#)), which gives
\begin{align}
I = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + u^2 - 2\rho u}du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + \rho}{1 - \rho}}\right).
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
P(X > Y > 0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + \rho}{1 - \rho}}\right). 
\end{align}
This agrees with the answer given in @Dilip Sarwate's comment (to verify, try matching derivatives of these two expressions).

---

An alternative approach makes use of the representation in your post. Assume $\rho \in (-1, 1)$ (the case $\rho = \pm 1$ is trivial), from the expression (I rewrote $X^i$ as $X_i$ to avoid confusion with exponents of $X$, and denote $\sqrt{\frac{1 - \rho}{1 + \rho}}$ by $\tau$ to save some typing)
$P(X > Y > 0) = P\left(X_2 > \tau X_1, X_1 > 0\right)$
that you have correctly derived and the condition that $X_1, X_2 \text{ i.i.d.} \sim N(0, 1)$, it follows that
\begin{align}
& P(X > Y > 0) = \int_0^\infty P\left(X_2 > \tau x\right)\phi(x)dx 
= \int_0^\infty \left(1 - \Phi\left(\tau x\right)\right)\phi(x)dx \\
=& \frac{1}{2} - \int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\tau x}\phi(y)\phi(x) dydx \\
=& \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\tau x}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)\right) dydx, \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
where $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ and $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(y)dy$.

It turns out that applying polar coordinates $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ to $\eqref{4}$ would make the integration more straightforward (than to $\eqref{1}$). Indeed, by observing that the integration region $\{(x, y): x > 0, y < \tau x\}$ in the Cartesian coordinate system is the integration region $\{(r, \theta): r > 0, \cos\theta > 0, \sin\theta < \tau\cos\theta\} = \{(r, \theta): r > 0, \theta \in (0, \arctan\tau) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)\}$ in the polar coordinate system, the integral in $\eqref{4}$ under polar coordinates becomes:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\arctan\tau}\int_0^\infty re^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}drd\theta + \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty re^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}drd\theta 
= \arctan\tau + \frac{1}{2}\pi. \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}
Substituting $\eqref{5}$ back to $\eqref{4}$ yields
\begin{align}
P(X > Y > 0) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\tau
= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 - \rho}{1 + \rho}}\right).  \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}
Since $\arctan(x^{-1}) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)$ when $x > 0$, $\eqref{6}$ agrees with the answer found in the first approach.

Comment: Thank you!  What  about $\rho = 1,-1$?

Comment: @ZhihaoXu with $\rho=-1$ you will get $0$ as $X=-Y$ with probability $1$.  $\rho=1$ is a special case as $X=Y$ with probability $1$, so $P(X \ge Y \ge 0)=\frac12$ while $P(X > Y > 0)=0$

Comment: By the way, what I have done is plot $x^{1}$ is perpendicular to $x^{2}$ since they are independent in my  work. Then see how is the region $X>Y>0$ change and  compute the  region's angle then divided by 2 $\pi$ .

Comment: Thank you guys! Appreciate that for helping me!

Comment: Note that $\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + \rho}{1 - \rho}}\right) =\frac12  \arcsin(\rho) +\frac\pi4$