# Finding a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that projects a point to an eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^T$

Tags: optimization, covariance, covariance-matrix

Suppose $\mathbf{b}=[b_1,b_2]'$ is $2\times 1$ and $\mathbf{C}$ is a full-rank symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix which both are real and given. Now, consider the problem of finding a $2\times 2$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{b'}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{b}$ is in the same direction of one of the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^T$ (lets say the eigenvector correspodning to the bigger eigenvalue).

I have been looking a lot to find a solution for $\mathbf{A}$ through formulating the problem as an optimization problem. However, I have not been able to see what type of optimization problem this falls into. I appreciate it if you could introduce me to some references addressing a similar problem to this one, or outline the appropriate approach for solving such examples.

Comment: If $A$ is not further constrained, you can always choose $A$ so that $ACA^T = I$ (e.g. as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution)). In that case the covariance is isotropic/spherical, so the direction of $Ab$ will not matter. Can you expand on your goal?

Comment: Would $C$ happen to be symmetric?

Comment: @whuber yes, $\mathbf{C}$ is symmetric.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Based on your argument, clearly, the $\mathbf{A}$ you introduced is not what we are after. We want an $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{A}b$ points in a certain direction.

Comment: From your title, I was inferring that $C$ is a covariance matrix. Then $\hat{C} = ACA^T$ is the [transformed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) covariance. Both covariances can be visualized as [ellipses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24380), so the "direction" is along the major axis of the ellipse. I was pointing out that $A$ can be chosen so that $\hat{C}$ is a circle, i.e. with no preferred orientation. Did you intend to define the direction independently of $A$?

Comment: No, the direction is controlled by $\mathbf{A}$ (via $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^T$); at the same time, the projection is also done by $\mathbf{A}$ (via $\mathbf{A}b$). I don't see the logic behind your phrase "$\mathbf{A}$ can be chosen". It is our objective to find an $\mathbf{A}$ to satisfy a certain goal; it is not for us to choose an $\mathbf{A}$. In other words, $\mathbf{A}$'s components are optimization variables, and the solution of course depends on $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Often, it's easiest (and insightful) to solve problems of linear algebra using algebraic or geometric methods rather than trying to cast them as optimization problems.**

This meta-principle is justified by the fact that many linear algebraic problems, such as this one, make sense for arbitrary ground fields (and often for mere [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) of scalars) but the optimization framework requires the ground field to be the real numbers or one of their [field extensions,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) making optimization a (much) more limited technique.

---

Assume $b$ is nonzero (for otherwise, if we understand "in the same direction as" means "is a *nonzero* multiple of," there is no solution).

Pick any $\lambda\gt 0$ and **let $A$ be a square root of $\lambda C^{-1};$** that is, choose $A$ such that $$A^\top A = \lambda C^{-1}.$$

(This strategy works very generally.  In the present case, because $C$ is real symmetric, such a matrix $A$ exists and can be found with, say, a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).)

Since $C$ is of full rank so therefore is $C^{-1},$ whence $A$ must be invertible.  Consequently

$$\left(ACA^\top\right)b^\prime= A\left(C^{-1}\right)^{-1}A^\top\,b^\prime = A\left(\lambda^{-1} A^\top A\right)^{-1}A^\top\,b^\prime = A \lambda A^{-1} \left(A^\top\right)^{-1} A^\top\,b^\prime = \lambda\, b^\prime$$

demonstrates *every* vector $b^\prime$ satisfies the eigenvector equation for $ACA^\top$ (with eigenvalue $\lambda$).  Because $b^\prime = A b$ is nonzero if and only if $b$ is nonzero (due to the invertibility of $A$), $b^\prime$ is an eigenvector of $ACA^\top$ with eigenvalue $\lambda,$ *QED.*

Comment: Thanks! Can anything be said regarding the part that we want $\mathbf{A}b$ to be in the direction of the _biggest_ eigenvalue of  $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^T$? (for example for the case $2\times 2$ matrices)

Comment: Since all eigenvalues of $ACA^\top$ are equal, automatically $Ab$ is an eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.